# Is epimorphism preserved under taking sections?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, epimorphisms

Let $\phi:\mathscr{F}\rightarrow\mathscr{G}$ be en epimorphism of sheaves (say, of rings) on $X$. Is it true that $\phi(U):\mathscr{F}(U)\rightarrow\mathscr{G}(U)$ is an epimorphism of rings for every open subset $U\subset X$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A counterexample (specialised from Gunning/Rossi, Analytic Functions of Several Complex Variables, Chapter VI):

Let $D$ an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathscr{F}$ the sheaf of germs of constant (complex valued) functions ($\mathscr{F}_z \cong \mathbb{C}$ for all $z \in D$). Let $\mathscr{K}$ be the subsheaf of $\mathscr{F}$ with stalk $0$ in two points $a < b$, and stalk $\mathbb{C}$ everywhere else. Let $\mathscr{G}$ be the quotient sheaf $\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{K}$. $\mathscr{G}$ has stalk $0$ above all points except $a$ and $b$, where it has stalk $\mathbb{C}$.

We have a short exact sequence

$$0 \to \mathscr{K} \to \mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{G} \to 0$$

of sheaves, but $\Gamma(U,\,\mathscr{F}) \to \Gamma(U,\,\mathscr{G})$ is not surjective for any connected $U$ containing both $a$ and $b$, since a section of $\mathscr{G}$ can take different values in $a$ and $b$, but a section of $\mathscr{F}$ must be constant.

If you want to avoid $\{0\}$-rings, consider

$$0 \to \mathscr{K} \oplus 0 \to \mathscr{F} \oplus \mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{G} \oplus \mathscr{F} \to 0.$$

For sheaves above paracompact Hausdorff spaces $D$, a short exact sequence

$$0 \to \mathscr{R} \to \mathscr{S} \to \mathscr{T} \to 0$$

induces a short exact sequence

$$0 \to \Gamma(D,\, \mathscr{R}) \to \Gamma(D,\,\mathscr{S}) \to \Gamma(D,\,\mathscr{T}) \to 0$$

for example if $\mathscr{R}$ is a *soft* sheaf (any section over a closed subset $K \subset D$ can be extended to a section over all of $D$).

Comment: Remember that epimorphism in the category of rings is not necessarily surjective. Are you sure you are not confusing the two?

Comment: @ashpool What, an epimorphism in the category of rings need not be surjective? That comes as a surprise. What is an epimorhism in the category of rings?

Comment: @Daniel: it's a right-cancellative morphism in the category of rings. They are somewhat hard to describe explicitly. But, for example, every localization $R \to S^{-1} R$ is an epimorphism, and these are usually not surjective. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like for a discussion.

Comment: By an "epimorphism," I meant it in the category theoretic sense: $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an epimorphism if for every morphisms $g,h:Y\rightarrow Z$, $g\circ f=h\circ f$ implies $g=h$. For example, in the category of rings, the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism, but not surjective.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I just also found that one via google. Bloody category theorists. Take old venerable words and give new strange meanings to them.

Comment: @ashpool Nevertheless, $\Gamma(D,\, \mathscr{F}) \cong \mathbb{C}$, and $\Gamma(D,\, \mathscr{G}) \cong \mathbb{C}^2$, and I'm pretty sure that $z \mapsto (z,z)$ is not an epimorphism in the category of rings (consider $g = \pi_1$ and $h = \pi_2$).

Comment: You are right, $z\rightarrow(z,z)$ is not an epimorphism. But I have a few issues with your answer. First of all, by a "sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ of constant functions on $D$," do you mean $\mathscr{F}(U)=\mathbb{C}$ for every nonempty open subset $U\subset D$? If so, there is no such a sheaf.

Comment: @ashpool Sheaf of germs of constant functions. There sure is such a sheaf (well, unless the meaning of sheaf has changed, since I learned a bit of that stuff). You then have $\mathscr{F}(U) \cong \mathbb{C}$ for all _connected_ $U \subset D$, but of course not for disconnected $U$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm more used to the term "constant sheaf associated with $\mathbb{C}$" for such a sheaf. In that case, I think you are right -- I think your answer does supply a counter example...

Answer (score 1):

The failure of this is the starting point for one of the main tools of algebraic geometry: Sheaf cohomology (see [MO/38966](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38966/what-is-sheaf-cohomology-intuitively) for a nice motivation). A basic example is the [exponentiel sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_sheaf_sequence). Complex logarithms exist locally, but not globally.